# Enabling component error 1009

Tags: apache-flex

I want to enable a linkbar component. When I run the application and try to look for data into the linkbar I get error 1009: impossible to acess property or method of a null object reference. How can I enable a component in flex so that to avoid error 1009? Any help would be appreciated...

```
<mx:LinkBar dataProvider="myViewStack" enabled="true"  activate="true"/>
  <mx:ViewStack id = "myViewStack" width="624" height="212" enabled="true">
      <mx:Canvas id="canvas3" label="Financement" enabled="true" >
       <mx:Label x="38" y="10" text="Code Fin."/>
           <mx:Label x="19" y="36" text="Fond propre" enabled="true"/> 
          </mx:Canvas>
 </mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: What makes you think the LinkBar is not enabled?  How are you trying to look for data in the LinkBar?  What is the line of code that gives an error 1009?  Activate is an event that the LinkBar dispatches; but you are setting it to `true`.  I'm not sure what setting it to true will accomplish.

Comment: When you get that error, there is a line number that tells which line in your code the error occurs on. We can't answer your question because without that line number we can only guess at what is `null`. Please add the error, and any relevant code with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:LinkBar dataProvider="{myViewStack}" enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here.  I think you are recommending that the dataProvider should be "Bindable" so that Flex thinks it is a variable as opposed to a literal.

Comment: Hmm, OP seemed to have edited the question right after posting it (I did answer it right after it came up): the original seemed to have mx:Linkbar component malforme, now it seems more that the null object ref comes from some other part, not the myViewStack itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "myViewStack" is initialized or not

Comment: how do i initialize myviewstack